# Parse XML file in Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net, button, combobox

*Yes, I am aware of the myriad of posts related to this topic; I've been unable to find my answer, however.*

I'm making a character editor for an RPG and I need a combo box to load things from a file in the Debug folder. I got the saving down pat; the loading is what's getting me.

My rep isn't high enough to post pictures so I'll try to explain it thoroughly.

There are two combo boxes and three buttons.

The first combo box is where the user enters the name of the characters they want and press the "Add" button to save it for later. Then once the user enters all the names of the characters they press the "Save" button which saves them in an XML file that looks like this, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <character>
    <name0>Banana</name0>
  </character>
  <character>
    <name1>Fruit</name1>
  </character>
  <character>
    <name2>Grapes</name2>
  </character>
  <character>
    <name3>Oranges</name3>
  </character>
  <character>
    <name4>Taco</name4>
  </character>
  <character>
    <count>5</count>
  </character>
</DocumentElement>
```

Notice at the end there is always a "character" named *count*. This is the number of names that were entered. This may or may not continue to be necessary based on what solution you happen to have. I'm always looking for a more efficient way to do this so I will post the code I used for saving the names as well.

```
   Private Sub saveFile(ByVal filename As String)

        count = NameBox.Items.Count
        REM create xml schema
        Dim table As New DataTable("character")


        Try
            For x = 0 To count

                If x <= count - 1 Then
                    table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("name" & x.ToString(),     
        System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
                    REM copy character data into datatable
                    Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
                    row("name" & x.ToString()) = NameBox.Items.Item(x)
                    table.Rows.Add(row)
                End If

                If x = count Then
                    table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("count", 
        System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
                    Dim row2 As DataRow = table.NewRow()
                    row2("count") = count.ToString()
                    table.Rows.Add(row2)
                End If
            Next


            table.WriteXml(filename)
            table.Dispose()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
  End Sub

 Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As   
    System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
        Save1.DefaultExt = ".char"
        Save1.Filter = "Character Data Files|*.char"
        Save1.Title = "Save Character File"
        Save1.InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
        Dim result As DialogResult
        result = Save1.ShowDialog(Me)
        If result <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then Return
        g_filename = Save1.FileName
        saveFile(g_filename)

  End Sub
```

Note:

Save1 is a SaveFileDialog. NameBox is the first combo box. SupportBox is the second. These are my globals— g_filename as String, count as Integer

Now, let's get into the actually loading of this file. Here's what I've tried and of course I get the notorious error "Object reference is not set to the instance of an object" which is the elaborate way of saying "You done goofed with indexing or whatever."

I've tried various things online and from my own knowledge. Instead of posting all of my attempts I'll just leave it at this.

Basically, what I'm wanting is for the file to be loaded into the second combo box (SupportBox) upon pressing the Load button.

The *count*, as you may guess, was seemingly needed for inclusion in the file so the loop would know how far to go when loading all the things in the file, in the attempt of preventing index errors; it was also needed so that the program would work without initially loading in the names, thus adding to the count. The Load button needs to function alone.

How would I go about loading this file?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit:

As per request, I'll post some code on *one* attempt I made to load this file.

```
Private Sub loadName(ByVal filename As String)
    Try

        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load(filename)
        Dim list As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("character")

        Dim element As XmlElement = list(0)

        For x = 1 To count
            SupportBox.Items.Add(getElement("Name" & x.ToString(), element))
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Function getElement(ByVal field As String, ByRef element As   
   XmlElement) As String
    Dim value As String = ""
    Try
        value = element.GetElementsByTagName(field)(0).InnerText
    Catch ex As Exception
        REM ignore error, just return empty

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
    Return value
End Function
```

Comment: all that and no question.  if you are trying to fix the NullReferenceException in the loading of the file, you should say so, show that code, tell us *what line* it happens on.  See also [Ask]

Comment: a) since you saved it with DT.WriteXML, you could reload it by DT.ReadXML b) the DT is convoluted - you changed rows into columns c) gluing the index onto "name" is needless d) `count` is just meta data - you could get that from the number of rows in the DT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object model is simple enough to where you don't need to use a DataTable for XML deserialization/serialization.  I try to avoid using DataTables for that in general anyways as I find the following approach easier.

Here is a common way of deserializing and serializing objects:

```
Private Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal strXML As String) As T

    Dim objXMLSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
    Dim objStringReader As New System.IO.StringReader(strXML)

    Return objXMLSerializer.Deserialize(objStringReader)

End Function

Private Function Serialize(ByRef TargetObject As Object) As String

    Dim objXmlSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(TargetObject.GetType())

    Dim objStringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter()

    objXmlSerializer.Serialize(objStringWriter, TargetObject)

    Return objStringWriter.ToString()

End Function
```

Next, create a Method for writing the XML File.  You'll notice it uses the Serialize() Function from above.  Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub Write()

    Dim lstCharacters As New List(Of character)

    For x = 0 To (count - 1)

        Dim objCharacter As New character
        objCharacter.name = NameBox.Items.Item(x)

        lstCharacters.Add(objCharacter)

    Next

    IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Some\Path.xml", Serialize(lstCharacters))

End Sub
```

Next, create a Method for loading the XML File.  This one uses the Deserialize() Function from above.  See how I easily get the Count in this Method.

```
Private Sub Read()

    Dim lstCharacters As List(Of character) = Deserialize(Of List(Of character))(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Test\TestSO1.xml"))

    Dim intCharacterCount As Integer = lstCharacters.Count

    For Each objCharacter As character In lstCharacters

        'SupportBox.Items.Add(getElement("Name" & x.ToString(), element))

    Next

End Sub
```

With this solution you no longer have to use the DataTable or worry about the Count.  The XML generated will be different than your original solution, but cleaner as the index is no longer appended on the name element.

Comment: Thanks. It says 'character' is not defined. I'm assuming that would be a global String variable?

Comment: My apologies for the late response.  character would be a class you define with the single string Property of Name.